# LemonWebSecurityConfig customization

Tags: spring-boot, spring-lemon

I use SpringLemon for my project. I would like to customize `authorizeRequests` method so that any request that starts with *"/xyz"* is only accessible for authenticated users. (*"/xyz/abc", /xyz/def", "xyz/ghi/jkl"*, etc.)
In order to do this, I made my own class extending `LemonWebSecurityConfig` class, and made it a configuration class. I've overridden `authorizeRequests` method to look like this:

```
@Override
    protected void authorizeRequests(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/xyz/**").authenticated()
            .mvcMatchers("/**").permitAll();                  
    }
```

As I tested it, it worked for those "*/xyz*" URLs (got 403 without authentication), "*/api/core/context*" gave me "200", but the "*/api/core/login*" URL always gave me 404. It responses with 404 even if I don't override `authorizeRequests` method and I only have the empty Configuration class. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I extended a wrong class. Using the right class (as it is seen in lemon-demo-jpa) it works perfectly:

```
@Component
public class MySecurityConfig extends LemonJpaSecurityConfig {

    @Override
    protected void authorizeRequests(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/xyz/**").authenticated();
        super.authorizeRequests(http);
    }
}
```